# TSQL convert datetime to int error

Tags: t-sql

SQL is giving an error on this line:

`IF YEAR(@Var_Report_To)%(4)=0 AND MONTH(@Var_Report_To)>=3`

> Error: Implicit conversion from data type datetime to int is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: The error is not on that line. Note that line numbers in error statements can be misleading in SQL Server. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/1160296/27535 for example

Comment: You're not trying to implement leap year detection yourself, are you? If so, you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your variable is a legit date, I don't see a problem with your expression. The following runs fine for me:

```
DECLARE @Var_Report_To DATETIME = '2016-03-01';

IF YEAR(@Var_Report_To)%(4)=0 AND MONTH(@Var_Report_To)>=3
SELECT GETDATE()
```